# Froala WYSIWYG reset all changes

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg, froala

I'm working on project which used Frola 1.2 WYSIWYG editor.

I can't use latest Frola editor (v2). I need add a reset button. When user presses on reset button, it must remove inline editor and revert all changes. How to do it?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Almost nothing. Searched from google, no results. Also couldn't find anything useful from official document.

Answer (score -4):

check this and read carefully

https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/customize

Comment: check 
this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26335916/froala-custom-close-button

Comment: Question was not about customization. However that undo: !0 looks interesting. Will dig deeper on that.